# Why does lucene phrase search return empty results?

Tags: lucene, umbraco, umbraco6

I would like to run a phrase search query on a Lucene 2.9 index and it doesn't return any results. The query is now stripped down to a very basic one but it still doesn't help. Where do I need to look at?

My failing search query is:

```
bodyText: "foo bar"
```

A query like the following works:

```
bodyText: (+foo +bar)
```

However the last query doesn't fit our purpose because I need a proper phrase search with words being in consecutive order.

I'm using Luke to test lucene queries.

Comment: And how are you indexing? The phrase "foo bar" means "the term foo, directly followed by the term bar" which implies analyzers that support positional information (which many do). The query "+foo +bar" just means "must contain foo and bar", and they can be present anywhere, in any order (and at the same position...)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, are you using the same analyzer when querying with Luke, as when you indexed your content? The default one for Luke (v 1.0.1) seems to be KeywordAnalyzer, so if you index your content with another analyzer, e.g. StandardAnalyzer and then try to query it with the KeywordAnalyzer it might not give the expected results.

I index content with StandardAnalyzer and phrase search in Luke works properly, providing that I use StandardAnalyzer when searching.

If the above is not the solution, you could also post your indexset and indexer configuration and the text you are indexing. This would allow recreating the issue.